# Htmlunit JavaScript Execution

Tags: htmlunit, htmlunit-driver

I am planning to develop code for measure Web page loading time using HtmlUnit

Below is my code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
    webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
    final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://www.gmail.com/");
    long time = page.getWebResponse().getLoadTime();
    long loadEventEnd = Long.parseLong(page.executeJavaScript("window.performance.timing.loadEventEnd").getJavaScriptResult().toString());
    long navigationStart = Long.parseLong(page.executeJavaScript("window.performance.timing.navigationStart").getJavaScriptResult().toString());
    long timejs = loadEventEnd-navigationStart;        
    System.out.println("Html Unit Time : " + time + " JS Time : "+timejs);
}
```

when i execute the code each every time i got **same result in the "timejs"**

(i am comparing both times as a test)

i am stuck in here, please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timing API is more or less a mock at the moment (version 2.32).
Have a look at the [code](https://sourceforge.net/p/htmlunit/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/htmlunit/src/main/java/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/javascript/host/performance/PerformanceTiming.java).

As always patches are welcome.